# Facebook Graph API Photos Response Changed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Facebook Graph API version has [changed](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) to 2.4 yesterday. I have been testing using Graph API Explorer and response to `/me/photos` request has changed. It returns only one photo. Is there a way to get all the photos as it was in v2.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

`/me/photos` actually only returns tagged photos.

You need to request `me/photos?type=uploaded` to get all the photos you uploaded.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of their difference. What I am asking is how to get responses from `/me/photos/tagged` and `/me/photos/tagged` as in v2.3.

Comment: It hasn't changed, you require user_photos permission. That's all.

Comment: It's working fine for me. You may try revoke all app permissions & grant again using v2.4 instead.

Comment: Checked that, no difference. Do you use `/me/photos/tagged` or `/me/photos/uploaded` query to request ?

Comment: Also, do you check using [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) ? @1lastBr3ath